# How to modify response in a single place

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for a single place in play framework 2.0.4 Java to modify the response.

Use case:
Load some user object within the GlobalSettings.onRequest() method. That works, but I also need to set a cookie. Either I need access to the response(), or to the session(). Neither seems to be available in the onRequest() method. And there is no onResponse() method.

The only way I see right now is to call a method within every controller's method that returns a Result.

**UPDATE**
The link I had originally posted here is dead now. Instead I've found this http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaActionsComposition which explains the same thing as the accepted answer below. Also, the comment about controller annotations is useful.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that when using Action Composition you can add an annotation directly to the Controller class instead of to every single action method inside it. That would save you a bit of trouble, though Marius Soutier's answer is the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java this seems to be much harder than in Scala. The basic idea is to wrap every action with a custom action that upon being called adds a header and calls the original method (the `delegate`). This is the exact same mechanic as in Java action composition.

This solution works for me but isn't extensively tested, so please check if all of your actions still work.

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

  private class ActionWrapper extends Action.Simple {
    public ActionWrapper(Action action) {
      this.delegate = action;
    }

    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws java.lang.Throwable {
      Result result = this.delegate.call(ctx);
      Http.Response response = ctx.response();
      response.setHeader("X-My-Header", "100");
      return result;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Action onRequest(Http.Request request, java.lang.reflect.Method actionMethod) {
    return new ActionWrapper(super.onRequest(request, actionMethod));
  }

}
```